# How to find topmost NSPanel

Tags: macos, cocoa

My app creates several floating panels (of class NSPanel) containing exclusively NSButtons. I need to find programmatically which of these panels is topmost at a given moment.

Unfortunately [NSApp orderedWindows] does not include windows which are in the NSFloatingWindowLevel level.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo) to retrieve all windows in the system and check the ones that belong to your process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I suspected I would have to go  that way. In fact, I ended up with a similar solution based on [NSWindowList()][1] instead of CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(). But since NSWindowList() is flagged as deprecated, I'll give CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo a try.
  
  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSWindowList

Comment: Apple keeps deprecating stuff in almost every SDK update, I'm suspecting one of their engineers is deprecating hobbyist :)